# Suggestion to add "lossless" and "no-reencoding" tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-request

I suggest adding `lossless` and `no-reencoding` tags,

###### What are these tags?

- `lossless` tag is to be used for the operations requiring no quality loss.
- `no-reencoding` tag is de facto subset or `lossless` tag where the medium isn't re-encoded.

Here is the example table,

| Action | Can be `lossless` | Can be `no-reencoding` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Changing audio codec from ALAC to MP3 | ❌ | ❌ |
| Changing audio codec from ALAC to WAV | ✔️ | ❌ |
| Changing container from MKV to MP4 | ✔️ | ✔️ |

Note: While some operations may be `lossless` or even `no-reencoding`, people often don't explicitly want to have these properties in the end result.

###### Why are those useful?

I used to collect the software and solutions I can use for explicitly lossless (and even no-reencoding) video operations (such as frame-perfect cuts, no-reenconding frame-imperfect cuts, video concatenation, video conversion, encoding pictures and audio into a singular video file and so on). I'd find, and later verify the information I find on Doom9 or VideoHelp.

Given we now have a stackexchange for video operations, I hope I can carry across some of that information over here, for future use.

As a user, one can then find all lossless (and no re-enconding information) by filtering against these tags.

###### Suggested tag aliases,

- `lossless` - `without-quality-loss`, `no-quality-loss`
- `no-reencoding` - `without-reencoding`

###### Questions that can make use of these tags,

- [Using ffmpeg to add height (as black bars) to video file without quality loss](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/24755) - `lossless` tag
- [Convert mp4 to webm without quality loss with ffmpeg](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/19590) - `lossless` tag, possibly `no-reencoding` tag
- [How to cut part of MP4 file using FFmpeg without reencoding?](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/32258) - both `lossless` and `no-reencoding` tag

Answer (score 1):

I added a lossless tag, though I didn't add a no-reencoding tag.  Lossless is a more general concept that I think makes sense to have categorized, but no-reencoding is a much more specific concept that is far more limited in scope and far more specific to the format or tool in question.

I'm open to being convinced of the value or maybe another user will see enough value in it, but I'm just not seeing the value of that particular tag right now.

I think part of it comes down to the fact that lossless can be both a concern for the question as well as a concept.  It's a much broader concern than specifically wanting to do operations without needing to re-encode.

Comment: I agree - lossless and no-reencoding have overlap but are not the same.